# Is there a text editor called Condo?

Tags: text, editor, text-editor

I was scrolling through the results of the StackOverflow survey for 2023 and saw that 152 people use Condo for their text editor/development environment. I searched for a long time and couldn't find anything on it. Does anybody have any idea what they are talking about.

[https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/](https://stackoverflow.com)
the link, just ctrl + f and search for condo if you would like to see.

I searched for a long, long time. Tried searching with quotes, excluding the word condominium, searching on specific operating systems, asking around, and more.